# How to refactor React code to include less of 'this.state'

Tags: reactjs

I have a class in a React project with 2 saved states:

```
import SoundData from './sounds.json';    
class SoundReading extends React.Component {
    state = { 
        data: SoundData.sounds,
        index: 0
    }...
 }
```

Throughout the rest of my code, I'm constantly calling 'this.state.data...' and 'this.state.index'.

I know we can remove 'this.state' inside a const by including the prop name(s) as a parameter wrapped inside of curly brackets.

```
const SongDetail = ({ song }) => {...}
```

But in this current situation, I'm pulling this data directly from a JSON into the component I'm working in.

How can I refactor my code so I don't have to constantly write and read 'this.state'?

Answer (score 4):

Destructuring

```
const { data, index } = this.state;
```

Comment: I tried this but it gave me a 'Unexpected token error, and pointed to the opening { after const.